# Coincidence of the determinant and eigenvalue of Hermitian matrix or unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I noticed that

1. the determinant and any eigenvalue of a Hermitian (self-adjoint) matrix both are real.
2. the determinant and any eigenvalue of a unitary matrix both have absolute $1$.

**Is it just a coincidence?
or there is a geometric interpretation or intuitive explanation of these result.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is what a coincidence?

That the determinant, as well as each eigenvalue of a Hermitian matrix, is real?
No, since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.

That the determinant, as well as each eigenvalue of a unitary matrix, has absolute value $1$?
No, since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.

That Hermitian matrices have real eigenvalues and unitary matrices have
absolute value $1$ eigenvalues?
No, but for an interesting reason. Each unitary matrix $U$ has the form
$\exp(i H)$ for some Hermitian matrix $H$. So if $H$ has eigenvalues
$\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ (all real) then $U$ has eigenvalues
$e^{i\lambda_1},\ldots,e^{i\lambda_n}$.

Comment: Thanks! Since all eigenvalue of a Hermitian matrix are real, 
the product of them (the determinant) is real.
Similarly, since all eigenvalue of a unitary matrix are absolute $1$, 
the product of them (the determinant) is absolute $1$.

Despite finding determinant of these two kind of matrix is easier than finding their eigenvalue.